# SQLite - Match records data

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a database with a list of game related trades in it, and I'm trying to identify the trades that match. Let me explain better.

I have the following **records**:

```
UserID  GameID  PlatformID  RecivingGameID  RecivingGamePlatformID  PostID
1111    18      167         41              43                      2312451124
2222    41      43          18              167                     1276949826
3333    41      43          18              21                      6798639876
4444    41      43          90              167                     4587938698
```

In this table there is only **1 match**, between post `2312451124` and `1276949826`. This is because **both users** have the game that the other user wants for a specific platform.

So if I am the user `1111`, the only match I have to see is with the user `2222` and vice versa. Users `3333` and `4444` have **no matches** in the database.

**How can I identify the trades that match?**

*Here's what I tried*:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE UserID != 1111 AND (RecivingGameID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT GameID FROM Posts) AND GameID IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT RecivingGameID FROM Posts)) AND (RecivingGamePlatformID IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT PlatformID FROM Posts) AND PlatformID IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT RecivingGamePlatformID FROM Posts))
```

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE UserID != 1111 AND RecivingGameID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT GameID FROM Posts) AND GameID IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT RecivingGameID FROM Posts) AND RecivingGamePlatformID IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT PlatformID FROM Posts) AND PlatformID IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT RecivingGamePlatformID FROM Posts)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a self join:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM Posts p1 INNER JOIN Posts p2
ON p2.UserID <> p1.UserID 
AND (p1.GameID, p1.PlatformID) = (p2.RecivingGameID, p2.RecivingGamePlatformID) 
AND (p2.GameID, p2.PlatformID) = (p1.RecivingGameID, p1.RecivingGamePlatformID) 
WHERE p2.UserID = 1111;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=fb4406acc47f2145f757e2ad0e3c9be8).

Comment: It worked thanks, could you explain it to me please?

Comment: @Simonalbi the self join matches the rows of userid = 1111 with any row un the table where the GameID of userid = 1111 is equal to the other's RecivingGameID and also with the other columns PlatformID with RecivingGamePlatformID.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH
    Posts(UserID, GameID, PlatformID, RecivingGameID, RecivingGamePlatformID, PostID) AS (
        VALUES
            (1111, 18, 167, 41, 43, 2312451124),
            (2222, 41, 43, 18, 167, 1276949826),
            (3333, 41, 43, 18, 21, 6798639876),
            (4444, 41, 43, 90, 167, 4587938698)
    ),
    matches AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            src.UserID AS UserID, src.PostID AS PostID,
            dst.UserID AS RecivingUserID, dst.PostID AS RecivingPostID
        FROM Posts AS src, Posts AS dst
        WHERE src.GameID = dst.RecivingGameID
          AND dst.GameID = src.RecivingGameID
          AND src.PlatformID = dst.RecivingGamePlatformID
          AND dst.PlatformID = src.RecivingGamePlatformID
          AND src.UserID < dst.UserID
    )
SELECT * FROM matches;
```